# identificador único de usuario en Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow

Estoy empezando un proyecto de chatBot conversacional con dialogflow.
Quiero guardar algún identificador único del usuario en base de datos para que persista y pueda identificar al usuario en posteriores interacciones con el bot.

Mi idea es que el bot use el canal de google assistance y necesito saber antes de comenzar la conversación si el usuario es nuevo o no para personalizar las respuestas.
Tenía pensado que de alguna forma, en el default_welcome_intent conocer el id único de ese usuario.
¿Alguien puede orientarme por favor? Ya que estoy comenzando necesitaría algún ejemplo...documentación de referencia... cualquier recomendación me ayudaría,.
Muchísimas gracias de antemano.